# write data using pyodbc iterate over a dictionary

Tags: python

I have the below python snippet where I am parsing data from a dictionary, to produce into a table using pyodbc library.

```
import pyodbc
 
data = {
  "demographic": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "country": {
        "code": "AU",
        "name": "Australia"
      },
      "state": {
        "name": "New South Wales"
      },
      "location": {
        "time_zone": {
          "name": "(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney",
          "standard_name": "AUS Eastern Standard Time",
          "symbol": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      },
      "address_info": {
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "zip_code": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "country": {
        "code": "AU",
        "name": "Australia"
      },
      "state": {
        "name": "New South Wales"
      },
      "location": {
        "time_zone": {
          "name": "(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney",
          "standard_name": "AUS Eastern Standard Time",
          "symbol": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      },
      "address_info": {
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "zip_code": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "country": {
        "code": "US",
        "name": "United States"
      },
      "state": {
        "name": "Illinois"
      },
      "location": {
        "time_zone": {
          "name": "(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)",
          "standard_name": "Central Standard Time",
          "symbol": "Central Standard Time"
        }
      },
      "address_info": {
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "zip_code": "60611"
      }
    }
  ]
}

result = [(d["id"], d["country"]["name"], d["address_info"]["zip_code"]) for d in data["demographic"] if d["country"]["code"] == "US"]
```

Now I need to write this result to a table which has id, country_name, zip

I'm trying the below code but not sure how to loop over all the records where the country code is US and map the values to the parameter marker. I have the cursor setup but not how to read from the python dictionary.

```
for r in result:
    sql = """INSERT INTO tname (id, country_name, zip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"""
    
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Why do you care `if d["country"]["code"] == "US"`?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem? `params` clearly isn't defined... You need to use `r`, not `params` in the execute call

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I need to populate based on which country is selected and stuck with how to populate that filtered dataset?

Comment: Look at `print(result)`... Your data is filtered perfectly fine. You've already read from the dict. Move on to the next problem. As I said, what happens when you 1) correctly indent your cursor execute statement within the loop, and 2) actually use `r` value? 3) Where is cursor and conn actually defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not sure how to loop over all the records where the country code is US

You already have a loop. Just add a print statement

```
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

> how to read from the python dictionary.

You've already done that, assuming the above code prints what you expect. You have a list of tuples, now.

> map the values to the parameter marker

Try this

```
conn =... 
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = """INSERT INTO tname (id, country_name, zip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"""
for r in result:
    cursor.execute(sql, r)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: OneCricketeer, I have these elements in my tuple `[('1', 'USA', '54611'), 
 ('2', 'usa', ''), 
 ('3', 'USA', '')]` and run into `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: If that's what gets printed, then the code in your question doesn't match, because you're clearly only checking `== "US"`. Please edit your question to include the full stacktrace and your updated code

Comment: I was testing for different use cases and figured out there was an issue with the source data once that was addressed everything fell in place.